# liferay 5.2 redirection to mobile page

Tags: jquery-mobile, liferay

I work with liferay 5.2

I developed a Java EE application

I am currently working in mobile version

I find a problem since my application is not responsive

So my solution is to develop several mobile modules to consume with the mobile device

My problem is with the login page of liferay

I want to find a way to make the redirection

either redirect to mobile page or to the web page

the redirection to the web page is done with this way in the portal-ext.properties file

```
default.landing.page.path=/group/inbox
```

how can I add make the redirection to mobile page

**updated :**

using liferay 6  I can use this code and add test to make the redirection

```
public class LoginPostAction extends Action 

{

    public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ActionException {



                ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(
                        WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
                Device device =themeDisplay.getDevice() ;
                Dimensions dimensions = device.getScreenSize();
                float height = dimensions.getHeight();
                float width = dimensions.getWidth();

                String brand = device.getCapability("brand_name") ;

            }



}
```

this is the jar of liferay :

liferay-portal-service-6.1.1.jar

but i didn't find the way using liferay 5.2

Comment: You can use apache for redirection. https://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-how-to-redirect-users-to-mobile-or-normal-web-site-based-on-device-using-mod_rewrite

Comment: I have updated my question, I have  problem to get screenSize   using liferay 5.2  in order to distinguish the device

Comment: Liferay 5.2 is not updated for more than 6 years now. You should upgrade - and even further then your stated test went: 6.2 is the current version. This provides a far better responsive basic framework.